# Python: Invalid syntax when creating a dictionary with dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I enter a date followed by time using Python and flask. What is the problem?

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,jsonify
import datetime

app=Flask(__name__)


calendrier=[
{
    'start':2013-9-22 16:19:43,
    'end':2015-8-11 13:30:00
}}
```

Comment: The date strings should be in quotes; as they are strings.  Additionally, the closing bracket should be square `]`, not curly `}`, as this is a list not a dict.

Comment: try learning about how to store dates in variables meaningfully and about the syntax for creating lists and dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

As the title of your question asks for why is there an invalid syntax error then that is cause you are using a curly `}` brace to close your `calendrier` list instead of a square `]` bracket as well as the way you are storing the dates.

You should either store the date in string format as suggested by [S3DEV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6340496/s3dev) or as you have imported the datetime module use a datetime object to store the date which is recommended for you.
Try:

```py
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,jsonify
import datetime

app=Flask(__name__)


calendrier=[
{
    'start': datetime.datetime(2013,9,22,16,19,43),
    'end': datetime.datetime(2015,8,11,13,30,0)
}]
```

Comment: Agreed, `datetime` is an excellent suggestion - use-case dictating the method chosen. +1

Comment: thanks for acknowledging that. I think i'am flattered. :):):)